# How to use the vim quickfix mode for LaTeX?

Tags: vim, build-system

One nice feature of vim is the quickfix mode (:help quickfix) - after calling :make you can navigate through the error messages of e.g. your C compiler and vim jumps to the right locations.

How do I use that with pdflatex?

I mean most times I am only interested in errors and 'undefined reference' warnings (or something like that) - and not in over/under-full foo messages etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [latex-suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) plugin. If you do not want the all the functionality of latex-suite, you can just copy the values of `makeprg` and `errorformat`

Comment: I only want to use latex-suite folding (since I dislike latex-box's one). Do you know how can achieve that? I believe that just copying the folding.vim file is not enough.

Comment: @petobens: Please start a new question. It is unlikely that your question will be noticed in a comment.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the new [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130586/vim-nice-folding-function)