# vim: nice folding function

Tags: vim, code-folding

I use `Latex-Box` but I really like `vim-latex` (a.k.a Latex-Suite) folding. I tried to copy Latex-Suite's `folding.vim` file to my `ftplugin/tex` folder but cannot make it work. Has anyone written a nice folding function or uses Latex-Suite one without Latex-Suite full plugin?

Comment: I use Latex-Suite pretty much only for the folding, so I would really like to see an answer.

Comment: Untested: You could install `latex-suite` and then edit `ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim` and start deleting stuff from line 810 onwards (except, of course, line 824 that sources folding.vim).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've modified `Latex-Box` (excellent) folding in two ways:
i) since I only like to fold sections (parts, chapters, etc), the abstract environment and frames (in beamer class) I've added a new variable  `g:LatexBox_folded_environments` that controls which environments are folded ii) I changed the `LatexBox_FoldText()` to resemble `Latex-Suite`.

You should save this file as `ftplugin/tex/folding.vim` and it should work out of the box.

```
" Initialization {{{

if exists('b:loaded_mylatexfolding')
    finish
endif
let b:loaded_mylatexfolding=1

" }}}
" Set options {{{

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=LatexBox_FoldLevel(v:lnum)
setlocal foldtext=LatexBox_FoldText()

if !exists('g:LatexBox_fold_preamble')
    let g:LatexBox_fold_preamble=1
endif

if !exists('g:LatexBox_fold_parts')
    let g:LatexBox_fold_parts=[
                \ "appendix",
                \ "frontmatter",
                \ "mainmatter",
                \ "backmatter"
                \ ]
endif

if !exists('g:LatexBox_fold_sections')
    let g:LatexBox_fold_sections=[
                \ "part",
                \ "chapter",
                \ "section",
                \ "subsection",
                \ "subsubsection"
                \ ]
endif

if !exists('g:LatexBox_fold_envs')
    let g:LatexBox_fold_envs=1
endif
if !exists('g:LatexBox_folded_environments')
    let g:LatexBox_folded_environments = [
                \ "abstract",
                \ "frame"
                \ ]
endif

" }}}
" LatexBox_FoldLevel helper functions {{{

" This function parses the tex file to find the sections that are to be folded
" and their levels, and then predefines the patterns for optimized folding.
function! s:FoldSectionLevels()
    " Initialize
    let level = 1
    let foldsections = []

    " If we use two or more of the *matter commands, we need one more foldlevel
    let nparts = 0
    for part in g:LatexBox_fold_parts
        let i = 1
        while i < line("$")
            if getline(i) =~ '^\s*\\' . part . '\>'
                let nparts += 1
                break
            endif
            let i += 1
        endwhile
        if nparts > 1
            let level = 2
            break
        endif
    endfor

    " Combine sections and levels, but ignore unused section commands:  If we
    " don't use the part command, then chapter should have the highest
    " level.  If we don't use the chapter command, then section should be the
    " highest level.  And so on.
    let ignore = 1
    for part in g:LatexBox_fold_sections
        " For each part, check if it is used in the file.  We start adding the
        " part patterns to the fold sections array whenever we find one.
        let partpattern = '^\s*\(\\\|% Fake\)' . part . '\>'
        if ignore
            let i = 1
            while i < line("$")
                if getline(i) =~# partpattern
                    call insert(foldsections, [partpattern, level])
                    let level += 1
                    let ignore = 0
                    break
                endif
                let i += 1
            endwhile
        else
            call insert(foldsections, [partpattern, level])
            let level += 1
        endif
    endfor

    return foldsections
endfunction

" }}}
" LatexBox_FoldLevel {{{

" Parse file to dynamically set the sectioning fold levels
let b:LatexBox_FoldSections = s:FoldSectionLevels()

" Optimize by predefine common patterns
let s:foldparts = '^\s*\\\%(' . join(g:LatexBox_fold_parts, '\|') . '\)'
let s:folded = '\(% Fake\|\\\(document\|begin\|end\|'
            \ . 'front\|main\|back\|app\|sub\|section\|chapter\|part\)\)'

" Fold certain selected environments
let s:notbslash = '\%(\\\@<!\%(\\\\\)*\)\@<='
let s:notcomment = '\%(\%(\\\@<!\%(\\\\\)*\)\@<=%.*\)\@<!'
let s:envbeginpattern = s:notcomment . s:notbslash .
            \ '\\begin\s*{\('. join(g:LatexBox_folded_environments, '\|') .'\)}'
let s:envendpattern = s:notcomment . s:notbslash .
            \ '\\end\s*{\('. join(g:LatexBox_folded_environments, '\|') . '\)}'

function! LatexBox_FoldLevel(lnum)
    " Check for normal lines first (optimization)
    let line  = getline(a:lnum)
    if line !~ s:folded
        return "="
    endif

    " Fold preamble
    if g:LatexBox_fold_preamble == 1
        if line =~# '\s*\\documentclass'
            return ">1"
        elseif line =~# '^\s*\\begin\s*{\s*document\s*}'
            return "0"
        endif
    endif

    " Fold parts (\frontmatter, \mainmatter, \backmatter, and \appendix)
    if line =~# s:foldparts
        return ">1"
    endif

    " Fold chapters and sections
    for [part, level] in b:LatexBox_FoldSections
        if line =~# part
            return ">" . level
        endif
    endfor

    " Fold environments
    if g:LatexBox_fold_envs == 1
        if line =~# s:envbeginpattern
            return "a1"
        elseif line =~# '^\s*\\end{document}'
            " Never fold \end{document}
            return 0
        elseif line =~# s:envendpattern
            return "s1"
        endif
    endif

    " Return foldlevel of previous line
    return "="
endfunction

" }}}
" LatexBox_FoldText helper functions {{{

function! s:CaptionFrame(line)
    " Test simple variants first
    let caption1 = matchstr(a:line,'\\begin\*\?{.*}{\zs.\+\ze}')
    let caption2 = matchstr(a:line,'\\begin\*\?{.*}{\zs.\+')

    if len(caption1) > 0
        return caption1
    elseif len(caption2) > 0
        return caption2
    else
        let i = v:foldstart
        while i <= v:foldend
            if getline(i) =~ '^\s*\\frametitle'
                return matchstr(getline(i),
                            \ '^\s*\\frametitle\(\[.*\]\)\?{\zs.\+')
            end
            let i += 1
        endwhile

        return ""
    endif
endfunction

" }}}
" LatexBox_FoldText {{{

function! LatexBox_FoldText()
    " Initialize
    let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    let nlines = v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1
    let level = ''
    let title = 'Not defined'

    " Fold level and number of lines
    let level = '+-' . repeat('-', v:foldlevel-1) . ' '
    let alignlnr = repeat(' ', 6-(v:foldlevel-1)-len(nlines))
    let lineinfo = nlines . ' lines: '

    " Preamble
    if line =~ '\s*\\documentclass'
        let title = "Preamble"
    endif

    " Parts, sections and fakesections
    let sections = '\(\(sub\)*section\|part\|chapter\)'
    let secpat1 = '^\s*\\' . sections . '\*\?\s*{'
    let secpat2 = '^\s*\\' . sections . '\*\?\s*\['
    if line =~ '\\frontmatter'
        let title = "Frontmatter"
    elseif line =~ '\\mainmatter'
        let title = "Mainmatter"
    elseif line =~ '\\backmatter'
        let title = "Backmatter"
    elseif line =~ '\\appendix'
        let title = "Appendix"
    elseif line =~ secpat1 . '.*}'
        let title =  line
    elseif line =~ secpat1
        let title = line
    elseif line =~ secpat2 . '.*\]'
        let title = line
    elseif line =~ secpat2
        let title = line
    elseif line =~ 'Fake' . sections . ':'
        let title =  matchstr(line,'Fake' . sections . ':\s*\zs.*')
    elseif line =~ 'Fake' . sections
        let title =  matchstr(line, 'Fake' . sections)
    endif

    " Environments
    if line =~ '\\begin'
        " Capture environment name
        let env = matchstr(line,'\\begin\*\?{\zs\w*\*\?\ze}')
        if env == 'abstract'
            let title = 'Abstract'
        elseif env == 'frame'
            let caption = s:CaptionFrame(line)
            let title = 'Frame - ' . substitute(caption, '}\s*$', '','')
        endif
    endif

    return level . alignlnr . lineinfo . title . ' '
endfunction

" }}}
```

If you want to fold figures, tables and other environments you should add the functions `LabelEnv()`, `CaptionEnv()` and `CaptionTable()` from `LaTeX-Box/ftplugin/latex-box/folding.vim` and modify the `LatexBox_FoldText()` function to include the mentioned functions as its done in Latex-Box folding (but changing the format to the format that suits your needs).

Comment: Works like a charm (even in 2017 ;)). Why don't you put it in a tiny github repo like `latex-folding.vim`?
EDIT: ok, there is already https://github.com/matze/vim-tex-fold

Comment: @bijancn That github folding isn't that good.

Comment: Hey, @petobens I was thinking of uploading .vimrc and related files to GitHub. May I upload your folding as well mentioning that its yours? I'll provide a link to your answer here, if you allow.

Comment: Go ahead. I have it already on Github: https://github.com/petobens/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/ftplugin/tex/folding.vim

Comment: I have lots of keybindings in vim for latex, and when I use this folding method it takes much longer to load any keybinding. After I removed this folding method it was working fine. I am also not sure whether this folding method is what's causing this problem, but it does go away if I remove this.

Comment: I had the similar speed issue as @MahbubAlam:  While I liked folding.vim, I had to remove it because, when combined with [imaps.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=244) on large documents, vim slowed to a crawl.

Comment: Many thanks @petobens for the code. Which command should one use to fold chapter or section once your code has been copied?